# CSS Image Bootstrapping style content

Tags: html, css

I been trying to make an image to add into bootstrap so that it can reduce its size as i resize the window to mobile view.

so far this is my code::

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="user-profile-css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- bootstrap theme -->
<link href="user-profile-css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!--external css-->
<!-- font icon -->
<link href="user-profile-css/elegant-icons-style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="user-profile-css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />    
<!-- full calendar css-->
<link href="assets/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/bootstrap-fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="assets/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- easy pie chart-->
<link href="assets/jquery-easy-pie-chart/jquery.easy-pie-chart.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<!-- owl carousel -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="user-profile-css/owl.carousel.css" type="text/css">
<link href="user-profile-css/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Custom styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="user-profile-css/fullcalendar.css">
<link href="user-profile-css/widgets.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="user-profile-css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="user-profile-css/style-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="user-profile-css/xcharts.min.css" rel=" stylesheet">    
<link href="user-profile-css/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<section id="main-content">
          <section class="wrapper">            
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <img alt="img-responsive" class="img-responsive" src="images/mainicons/couponbox.png">
                </div>
              </div>
            </section>
</section>
<script src="user-profile-js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="user-profile-js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="user-profile-js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="user-profile-js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js"></script>
<!-- bootstrap -->
<script src="user-profile-js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- nice scroll -->
<script src="user-profile-js/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
<script src="user-profile-js/jquery.nicescroll.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- charts scripts -->
<script src="assets/jquery-knob/js/jquery.knob.js"></script>
<script src="user-profile-js/jquery.sparkline.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/jquery-easy-pie-chart/jquery.easy-pie-chart.js"></script>
<script src="user-profile-js/owl.carousel.js" ></script>
<!-- jQuery full calendar -->
<<script src="user-profile-js/fullcalendar.min.js"></script> <!-- Full Google Calendar - Calendar -->
<script src="assets/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js"></script>
<!--script for this page only-->
<script src="user-profile-js/calendar-custom.js"></script>
<script src="user-profile-js/jquery.rateit.min.js"></script>
<!-- custom select -->
<script src="user-profile-js/jquery.customSelect.min.js" ></script>
<script src="assets/chart-master/Chart.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

now whats the styling tags that makes it compatible to mobile view.

Comment: Add `img-responsive`.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has a helper utility class `img-responsive`.

```
<img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="new folder/couponbox.png">
```

PS. I am sure you did, but anyways, don't forget to set the `col-*-*` class to the `div` below `div.row`.

Comment: and what about bootstrap links that i presume i should add on head tag?

Comment: [Here](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) you go. It's all well documented.

Comment: Well, that's because you still haven't added the required class to your image tag as it is described the answer (`class="img-responsive"`).

Comment: no, i added it too.. i just forgot to add it in question.. though its still not working..

Comment: I guess some other CSS rule is overwriting it or bootstrap files are not loaded. Please use Chrome developer tools to identify the problem.